# Spring Boot App not consuming queue messages

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq

I have the Rabbit MQ broker for communicating asynchronously between services. **Service A** is sending messages to the queue. I checked the queue and the messages from Service A have arrived:
[image]

I am trying to create a listener in the **Service B** in order to consume the messages produced by Service A. I verified like below to check if Service B is connected with RabbitMQ and it seems to be connected successfully.

[image]

The problem is that Service B started successfully but it is receiving messages from Rabbit MQ.

Below is the implementation of the listener:

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class EventListener {

    public static final String QUEUE_NAME = "events";

    @RabbitListener(
            bindings = {
                    @QueueBinding(
                            value = @Queue(QUEUE_NAME),
                            exchange = @Exchange("exchange")
                    )

            }
    )
    public void handleTaskPayload(@Payload String payload) {
        System.out.println(payload);
    }
}
```

I verified the queue and exchange information in the Rabbit MQ and they are correct.

[image]

Everything is working correctly and there is no error thrown in service A or service B which makes this problem much harder to debug.

I tried to retrieve the message from the queue getMessage of RabbitMQ the message is like the below:

```
{"id":"1",:"name:"Test","created":null}
```

I will appreciate any help or guidance towards the solution of this problem.

Best Regards,
Rando.

P.S

I created a new test queue like the below and published some messages:

[image]

[image]

Modified the listener code like below and still wasn't able to trigger listener to listen to the queue events:

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class RobotRunEventListener {

    public static final String QUEUE_NAME = "test";

    @RabbitListener(
            bindings = {
                    @QueueBinding(
                            value = @Queue(QUEUE_NAME),
                            key = "test",
                            exchange = @Exchange("default")
                    )

            }
    )
    public void handleTaskPayload(@Payload String payload) {
        System.out.println(payload);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the spring boot app that I was working on had a `@Conditional(Config.class)` that prevented the creation of the bean below:

```
@Slf4j
@Conditional(Config.class)
@EnableRabbit
public class InternalRabbitBootstrapConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public RabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        factory.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(5);
        return factory;
    }
...
```

which resulted in the spring boot app not listening to Rabbit MQ events. The Config.class required a specific profile in order to enable the app to listen to Rabbit MQ events.

```
public class DexiModeCondition implements Condition {

    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {

        String[] activeProfiles = context.getEnvironment().getActiveProfiles();

        return activeProfiles[0].equalsIgnoreCase(mode);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

```java
 @RabbitListener(queues = "test")
 public void receive(String in, @Headers Map<String, Object> headers) throws IOException  {
 }
```

Comment: Thank your answer but this wasn't problem.